# Calling TagLib stuff in Grails console?

Tags: grails, grails-web-console

Is there a way to call a taglib closure from inside the grails console?  I want to be able to get at the message tag within the grails console and I can not figure this out...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can get the configured taglib, but most expect to be running in the context of a web request. To get around that you can bind a mock request:

```
import grails.util.GrailsWebUtil

GrailsWebUtil.bindMockWebRequest ctx

def g = ctx.getBean('org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.web.taglib.ValidationTagLib')
String message = g.message(code: 'default.button.delete.confirm.message')
```

You can also get messages for other languages by setting the locale of the request, e.g.

```
import grails.util.GrailsWebUtil

def webRequest = GrailsWebUtil.bindMockWebRequest(ctx)
webRequest.currentRequest.addPreferredLocale(Locale.GERMANY)

def g = ctx.getBean('org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.web.taglib.ValidationTagLib')
String message = g.message(code: 'default.button.delete.confirm.message')
```

Answer (score 3):

Using @Burt [console plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/console) this is even easier as we don't have to mock the web request...

```
import org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.web.taglib.ValidationTagLib

// Getting the class name to reduce horizontal
// scrolling in StackOverflow
def g = ctx.getBean(ValidationTagLib.class.getName())

g.message(code: 'default.button.delete.confirm.message');
```

You can get a list of all the tagLibs in your application by running this code in the console...

```
// prints a bean name per line.
ctx.getBeanNamesForType(Object).findAll {
    it =~ /.*TagLib$/
} .sort() {println it}

// add false to prevent console printing the map out
false
```